# How to Display week names in the given date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

For the Given date the Query should return the week names of particular date.

DECLARE @Date DATE = '2014-06-02 00:00:00.000'

If i given the the date as above it should return the week names of that particular week.

Expects output like this

```
______________________________________________________________________________________
   mon         tue         wed          thu         fri        sat         sun     
______________________________________________________________________________________
2014-06-02  2014-06-03  2014-06-04  2014-06-05  2014-06-06  2014-06-07  2014-06-08 
______________________________________________________________________________________
```

I have the table like this

```
____________________________________________________________
empID           empCheckInTime             empCheckOut
____________________________________________________________
1              Jun  2 2014 12:37 PM    Jun  2 2014 12:44 PM
2              Jun  6 2014 12:02 PM    Jun  6 2014 12:03 PM  
____________________________________________________________
```

My sql Query is

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2014-06-02 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2014-06-09 23:59:59.999'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEDIFF(HOUR,@StartDate,@EndDate))+'.' 
+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@StartDate,@EndDate)% 60)
AS NoOfHours
```

Help me with select query in SQL Server 2008

Comment: What have you tried so far?  SO usually frowns on "please do this thing for me" type questions.

Comment: Hint: Look up the `DATEADD` function

Comment: `Select Datename(dw,getdate())` Is to display week names

Comment: I need to display current week names not only today. Like if suppose i have given Getdate(). it should display like Mon 09/14  Tue 10/14 Wed 11/14 Thu 12/14 Fri 13/14 Sat 14/14 Sun 15/14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query:

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2014-06-02'


;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT @Date [Date],
         DATENAME(DW,@Date) DayOfTheWeek,
         1 i

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,[Date]),
         DATENAME(DW,DATEADD(DAY,1,[Date])),
         i + 1
  FROM CTE
  WHERE i + 1 <=7
)
SELECT DayOfTheWeek,
       [Date]
FROM CTE
ORDER BY i ASC
```